# How can I write output to a new external file with Perl?

Tags: perl

Maybe I am searching with the wrong keywords or this is a very basic question but I cannot find the answer to my question. I am having trouble writing the result of my whois command to a new external file.

My code is below. It takes `$readfilename`, which is a file name which has a list of IPs, and `$writefilename`, which is the destination file for output. Both are user-specified. For my tests, `$readfilename` contains three IP addresses on three separate lines so there should be three separate whois results in the user specified output file.

```
if ($readfilename) {
    open (my $inputfile, "<", $readfilename) || die "\n   Cannot open the specified file.     Please double check your file name and path.\n\n";
    open (my $outputfile, ">", $writefilename) || die "\n   Could not create write file.\n\n";
    while (<$inputfile>) {
        my $iplookupresult = `whois $_ > $writefilename`;
        print $outputfile $iplookupresult;
    }
    close $outputfile;
    close $inputfile;
}
```

I can execute this script and end up with a new external file, but over half of the file has binary garbage data (running on CentOS) and only one (or a portion of one) of the whois lookups is readable.

I have no idea how half of my file is ending up binary... but my approach must be incorrect. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Sorry, had an erroneous variable in the example from one of my tests. It has been removed.

Comment: I added the "erroneous" script back in so that other people can see how *not* to make stupid mistakes. I spent quite a while trying to debug this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using shell redirection to redirect the output of `whois` to a file. But you've also opened the file for writing and are attempting to write data to the same file, giving you garbage. Just drop the shell redirection:

```
print $outputfile `whois $_`;
```

Comment: You know whats funny -- that is the code I deleted from my example thinking it was erroneous. I just checked and it was actually still in my script as well during my tests... *sigh* Thanks!